# Concurrent upload of file in S3 -- prevent conflicting upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there any way to upload a file to S3 and force that an object be *created* in the operation, and *not updated*? (e.g. simulating `open(O_CREAT | O_EXCL)`)

i.e. I'd like my PUT OBJECT to fail if the file already exists. S3 does offer strong read-after-create consistency, so hopefully there's some way to take advantage of that.

Abstractly speaking, I wish to implement an operation `create_s3_object(s3_key, data)`, that any S3 client can call, to write `data` to a *new* S3 object designated by `s3_key`. The data and the key are known before issuing the call.

If all clients cooperate and use `create_s3_object(s3_key, data)` to create object `s3_key`, then the call should provide the following guarantees:

1. if file `s3_key` does not exist, then file `s3_key` is created with data `data` as its contents, and the call succeeds.
2. if file `s3_key` already exists, the call fails, and the existing file remains unmodified by the call. (I can loosen this requirement by tolerating the existence of file `s3_key` if and only if it contains exactly `data`)
3. if file `s3_key` does not exist, and multiple calls are issued concurrently from different clients (and/or from the same client) with different data: i.e. `create_s3_object(s3_key, data1)`, `create_s3_object(s3_key, data2)`, … `create_s3_object(s3_key, dataN)`, and then at most one of those calls will succeed, and the data of `s3_key` will match that provided by the one call that succeeded.
4. Atomicity. Assuming a file was created via `create_s3_object(s3_key, data)`, and never updated after creation, if any client performs a GET for `s3_key` at any point in time (before, during, or after creation), the client will have receive either a 404 error (before creation), or data `data`, but no other versions of the file (e.g. some transient state of `s3_key`).

Additional details:

- i'm using boto3 (python)
- the set of clients making potentially conflicting requests are: running on ECS containers (same region as the bucket), in lambda functions (same region as bucket), and one or two processes running on a desktop located on the public internet outside aws.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but you could potentially use bucket versioning as a way to detect that your upload was not the first version, and then deal with that situation.

Comment: Depending on where the uploads are coming from, you could use DynamoDBLockClient to “lock” on bucket+object so that only one upload can occur to a S3 object path at a time. If you provide more details about your use case, there’s probably a straightforward solution to your problem (even if it’s not the conditional PUT that you originally asked about).

Comment: Or potentially just a conditional put (with attribute_not_exists ) of an item representing the S3 object key into DynamoDB.

Comment: @jarmod that makes sense. I was thinking initially that there was a way to compose some form of semaphore with If-Not-Match and//or If-Match PUT/PUTCOPY operations on S3. but relying on another service with stronger guarantees seems easier.

Comment: Another option: instead of allowing clients to access the S3 bucket directly, you require them to interact with a small API that you build (Lambda and API Gateway). Your Lambda function basically is a vendor of pre-signed URLs for uploading to unique keys in S3. It could generate a UUID for the object in question and have the client upload to it. If UUIDs as keys is problematic for you because the filename is somehow important, then you could also build a small feature that deals with that (e.g. move UUID file from holding bucket to filename in target bucket or a DynamoDB key/value map).